# How can I show that particular functions are in the Schwartz class $\mathcal {S}(\mathbb{R} ^n)$?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

In his famous textbook *Fourier Analysis*, Stein asserts the following.

**If $f$ and $g$ are functions in the Schwartz class $\mathcal {S}(\mathbb{R} ^n)$, then $\hat f (\xi) \cos(|\xi|)$ and $\hat g(\xi) \frac{\sin(|\xi|)}{|\xi|}$ are also functions in the Schwartz class.**

Here, $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Also, $\hat f$ and $\hat g$ denotes the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $g$, resp. (In particular,  $\hat f$, $\hat g$ $\in \mathcal {S}(\mathbb{R} ^n)$.)

How can I prove this? Calculating the derivatives quickly becomes very messy since the functions involve the norm of $\xi$.

Comment: It is intuitively true that $\cos(|\xi|)$ has the properties that you have mentioned, but how can I really prove that?

Comment: That all the derivatives are polynomially bounded is immediate

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If $c(t)$ is even $C^\infty$ then $c(|x|)$ is $C^\infty$
- If all the derivatives of $c(t)$ are bounded then all the derivatives of $c(|x|)$ are bounded (around $x=0$ there is no problem and for $x\ne 0$, $|x+t v|^2 = |x|^2+2t \langle x,v\rangle +O(t^2)$ so $|x+tv| = |x|+ t \langle x/|x|,v\rangle+O(t^2)$).
- Thus if $h(x)$ is Schwartz and then so is $h(x) c(|x|)$. If the derivatives of $c(t)$ were polynomially bounded it would work too.
- If $f(y)$ is Schwartz then so is $\hat{f}(x)$